# 2D integration of scattered data (python)

Tags: python, integration

I have some scattered data along X and Y with value A. I want to integrate A over X and Y. However my data isn't on a cartesian grid (X,Y spacing between data points changes a lot) and the X,Y domain occupied by the data points is a complex shape (exact area unknown)

Is there an easy way to integrate such data?

Comment: What type of integration do you mean, some sort of discrete one over a grid/mesh?

Comment: @FallenApart yes a discrete integration would be nice.

Comment: could you say some about format of your data? Is it a one numpy array?

Comment: @FallenApart I have three 1D ndarray (for X , Y and A). A  data point i is (arrayX[i], arrayY[i], arrayA[i])

Comment: The data comes from a CDF mesh but I don't have access to the connectivity between the data points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done the following:

- triangulate the domain
- calculate the integral over each triangle
- sum the integrals over triangles (it can be done due to integral additivity property)

Let's say we have the following data:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1.5])
Y = np.array([0, 1.1, 0, 1, 1.3])
A = np.array([2, 1.1, 0.5, 2, 0.3])
```

We do the triangulation using `scipy`:

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
domain_points = np.array(list(zip(X,Y)))
tri = Delaunay(domain_points)
```

[image]

We compute the integral:

```
def area_from_3_points(x, y, z):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.cross(x-y, x-z), axis=-1)**2)/2
integral = 0
for vertices in tri.simplices:
    mean_value = (A[vertices[0]] + A[vertices[1]] + A[vertices[2]]) / 3
    area = area_from_3_points(domain_points[vertices[0]], domain_points[vertices[1]], domain_points[vertices[2]])
    integral += mean_value*area
print(integral)

Out: 2.1166666666666667
```